# get iis7 log directory within powershell

Tags: iis-7, powershell

I am sure this is easy, but I can not find the answer.  I am setting up a process to run a few tasks on the logging folder.  Obviously I can manually create a variable with the log directory but this does change from machine to machine.  I would like to be able to use some generic process.

What I have at the moment:

```
$iisLogDir = "D:\inetpub\Logs\LogFiles"
$now=get-date
$daysOld=31

get-childitem $iisLogDir -recurse | where { !$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.lastWriteTime -le $now.addDays(-$daysOld)) } | remove-item -whatif
```

Thanks, These are 2008R2 machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the IIS WebAdministration Module and the Get-WebConfigurationProperty cmdlet.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
(Get-WebConfigurationProperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults" -name logfile.directory).Value
```

Comment: I have a site which has had the log directory moved to D:\ and this reports '%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles. Am I correct in understanding that this is the default location, but a site may be in a different location and I need to find a different value?

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
(gi IIS:\Sites\$webSite).logfile.directory
```

Comment: It looks like you may have the knowledge to provide good Answer here, but please consider reading [How do I write a good Answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) in our help center and then revise the Answer. Your Commands/Code may technically be the solution  (I don't know) but  some explanation is welcome. Also is that code valid for Windows 2008? Because AFAIK significant improvements have been  in PS. Thanks in advance.